# Excel - Counting items in a list, ignoring text but counting numbers?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have some working code that will count the number of times a date occurs.

```
Stage   Date
1       07/16/18
1       07/16/18
2       07/16/18
2       07/16/18
1       07/16/18
3       07/16/18
1.2     07/17/18
3       07/17/18
2       07/17/18
4       07/17/18
Test1   07/17/18
3       07/17/18
5       07/17/18
5       07/18/18
```

It's a simple sumproduct, like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$300=A1))
```

Where Sheet2 contains the above list of stages and dates, A1 is the current date.

Right now, if the current date is the 07/17/18, it would show or count 7 "Stages", but I would like to set it up to ignore anything with text, like Test1, so that it will only count 6 Stages for that given day.

I have a feeling I'm missing something simple with the SUMPRODUCT, but I can't quite seem to find similar examples to use as inspiration.   I've thought of using COUNTIFS or subtracting an INDEX/MATCH value, but finding the syntax is beating me up right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then add a test for ISNUMBER:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((isnumber(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$300))*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$300=A1))
```

[image]

Comment: I see you are not slowing down any as you age

Comment: Argh.  If I recreate your example, it does the calculation properly and all is well.   If I substitute in the actual locations and items in my sheet, it just returns a zero.

Edit: Success!  Putting in (ISNUMBER(VALUE(stuffhere))) gets it!  You are a wonderful person - thank you so much for the speedy reply.

Comment: @MysteryMan try this: `=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(--Sheet2!$A$1:$A$300))*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$300=A1))`